# 301 .htaccess redirection from an URL that has a "?" character

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I want to redirect at .htaccess every URL that has inside it a "?" character to the root of my site (domain.com).

I have read this :

```
301-htaccess-redirect-with-special-characters
/how-to-make-htaccess-rule-for-a-url-with-specific-characters
```

But I still do not know how to do it. I know only a bit of regular expresions.

Examples Urls I would like redirect to the root of my site :

http://www.portaltarot.com/index.html?url=/MHL-Papus.html
http://www.portaltarot.com/index.phpindex.php?Itemid=249

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that. Blocking URLs with query strings can inadvertently block people from accessing your website. e.g. if you use AdWords and auto tagging the ads will break. email marketing with campaign tracking etc. If you do it, do it for specific values and not everything.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I have no Adwords, etc.

Comment: But others may. e.g. sometimes tweets go via url shorteners and utm tracking codes are added.

Check your logs to see if query strings are being used and if you want to block those visitors from seeing the content they expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mod_rewrite to do this, so something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=/MHL-Papus.html$ 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Itemid=249$
RewriteRule ^index\.phpindex\.php$ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: 1) First URL redirects to the root contain, but URL at navigator does not change, so partialy solved; Is it posible to change also the url to root domain ?

Comment: 2) Second URL finish with 404 (not found) redirects to http://www.portaltarot.com/?Itemid=249

Comment: to stop the query string being passed to the destination change the / to a /?  e.g.
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /? [L,R=301]